# Replace value in dataframe with another value in the same row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that looks something like this:

```
myid  user    start                     end
a     tom     2023-01-01T23:41:32       2023-01-02T23:41:32
b     dick    None                      2023-01-05T20:41:32
c     harry   2023-01-01T23:41:32       2023-01-03T21:41:32
d     sally   None                      2023-01-05T03:41:32
```

I am trying to replace the values of df["start"] which are equal to "None" with the respective value of df["end"] for that row entry:

```
myid  user    start                     end
a     tom     2023-01-01T23:41:32       2023-01-02T23:41:32
b     dick    2023-01-05T20:41:32       2023-01-05T20:41:32
c     harry   2023-01-01T23:41:32       2023-01-03T21:41:32
d     sally   2023-01-05T03:41:32       2023-01-05T03:41:32
```

This doesn't seem to work:

`df[df["start"]=="None"]["start"]=df[df["start"]=="None"]["end"]`

The entries with "start"== "None" remain unchanged.

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: `df['start'] = df['start'].fillna(df['end'])`, or `df.loc[df['start'].isna(), 'start'] = df['end']`

Comment: You approach failed as `df[df["start"]=="None"]["start"]` creates a new Series, which you modify and discard on the fly.

Comment: The value I wish to replace isn't NaN, its a string "None".

Comment: Then: `df.loc[df['start'].eq('None'), 'start'] = df['end']`. Or replace None with real NaN and use the first approach.